# Method Illuminate\View\View::response does not exist

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm getting an error when I want to fetch my data from table.

My controller :

```php
public function admin()
{
    $users = User::with('subs')->get();
    return view('admin')->response()->json([
        'users' => $users,
    ], 200);
}
```

My vue.js script :

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: []
        }
    },

    methods: {
        showUsers() {
            axios.get('admin/routes').then(response => {
                this.users = response.data.users;
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.showUsers();
    }
}
```

My blade html code:

```html
<tr v-for="user in users">
    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

> Method Illuminate\View\View::response does not exist.

When I want to fetch my data from table.

Comment: Your response is not set. Check to see if admin/routes is the right url path and if the web service returns any relevant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return view for that since you just need the JSON response for the API to work.

```
return response()->json([
    'users' => $users,
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine in your code just send only response because we only want database table's data, no need to return view.

```
return response()->json([
    'users' => $users,
]);
```